# Is there a reason not to use parametised routes in the Play Framework

Tags: web-applications, playframework, conventions

At work I am making some changes to an existing web app built using the Play Framework, and have noticed that none of the routes use parameters. On previous projects I've worked on I would expect to see routes like:

```
GET    /some-path/:id    @controllers.BaseController.somePath(id: Int)
```

Instead all the routes would be like so:

```
GET    /some-path        @controllers.BaseController.somePath()
```

In this case the web app uses a session manager to store and retrieve values, nothing is sent via parameters in the routes. I haven't seen this pattern before and don't have easy access to anyone who knows why the project was set up like this.

Is there any particular benefits to working like this? Is it more secure, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the reason they used session data to track what should be parameters is due to lack of knowledge on RESTful design, rather than a deliberate choice.

The reason you wouldn't want to store information in the session for request / response data is mainly due to the reason the session exists: storing data across multiple requests. For standard POST/GET operations the data being sent is only meant to last the lifespan of one request (POST a userID to an action, or GET a list to display on a page). Storing these in the session would break the purpose of the session and result in either unnecessary data being carried over to each request, or it would require you to remove the parameters from session data after you're done with the data.

You could theoretically store this data in "flash" to solve the problem of data persisting across requests, as the flash session in Play only lasts one request, however flash is not secure & can be modified, it is subject to race conditions, may not be compatible on older browsers, and is mainly meant to serve display / error messages that last the one request after they occur.